# No module named 'tensorflow' in Anaconda3 on a MacBook

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, path, anaconda

When I was trying to `import tensorflow` with my Anaconda3, JupyterLab gave this error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-64156d691fe5> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

I am sure that I have installed TensorFlow in both python and python3 on my MacBook:

```
⋊> ~ pip3 show tensorflow                                          11:54:49
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.13.0rc2
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: termcolor, tensorboard, keras-applications, keras-preprocessing, grpcio, numpy, six, absl-py, protobuf, wheel, astor, tensorflow-estimator, gast
Required-by:
```

`import tensorflow` with python3 in the terminal was also fine, but after I added the Anaconda path to the fish shell, it gave this error message:

```
⋊> ~ python3                                                        12:09:48
Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 14 2018, 13:28:58) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
>>>
```

Additionally, I just tried `conda install tensorflow`, result blow:

```
⋊> ~ conda install tensorflow                                       
12:24:09
    Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - anaconda==2018.12=py37_0 -> cython==0.29.2=py37h0a44026_0
  - anaconda==2018.12=py37_0 -> mkl-service==1.1.2=py37hfbe908c_5
  - anaconda==2018.12=py37_0 -> numexpr==2.6.8=py37h7413580_0
  - anaconda==2018.12=py37_0 -> scikit-learn==0.20.1=py37h27c97d8_0
  - tensorflow
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Comment: Anaconda doesn't come with tensorflow... just install it

Comment: if you can use the conda command intall using `conda install tensorflow`. This command will install the tensorflow on your current active environment.

Comment: `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages`: this doesn't look like anaconda path. try `pip show tensorflow`. what does it show

Comment: `pip show tensorflow` used to show something, but now showed nothing

Comment: try `which pip`. What's the path

Comment: also `which python`

Comment: `/Users/myusername/anaconda3/bin/pip` & `/Users/myusername/anaconda3/bin/python` seperately

Comment: ok. so yo should install tensorflow using `pip` and not `pip3`. what is happening is that mac comes with both python 2 (`python/pip`) and python 3 (`python3/pip3`). But once you installed anaconda, `python` and `pip` are "over-ridden" by anaconda...

Comment: OK, thanks. So I should use `pip install tensorflow` now?

Comment: yes. assuming you installed jupyterlab using `conda install .......`, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) and as you are using Mac with `Python3`, you can install it with `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But should I do `pip` or `pip3`?

Comment: Simply all the requirements were satisfied already. Nothing really done

Comment: If you are using Conda you should follow Conda install in the docs with a `venv`